# cell use random image

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have two `UICollectionView`:

1 `UICollectionView` - Post

2 `UICollectionView` - Categories

Logic:

When user tap on any `categories`, that we send new api request and then update `post collection view`

In my UICollectionViewCell have two conditions.

1 `Image Item`

2 `Video Item`

Below my code:

```
class PopularPostsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var myImage : UIImageView!

func setupItems(childPostsItem: ChildPostsModel, index: Int) {
    if childPostsItem.media_type != "video" {
        myImage.image = nil
        myImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: childPostsItem.media), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            let locImage = Helpers.videoSnapshot(filePathLocal: childPostsItem.media)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myImage.image = nil
                self.myImage.image = locImage
            }
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    myImage.image = nil
}
```

}

if `video`, I need get image from Video URL below my code:

```
static func videoSnapshot(filePathLocal: String) -> UIImage? {
    do {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: filePathLocal)!, options: nil)
        let imgGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        imgGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImage(at: CMTimeMake(0, 1), actualTime: nil)
        let thumbnail = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return thumbnail
    } catch let error {
        print("*** Error generating thumbnail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }        
}
```

Problem: If I choose several item in category very fast, my cell use random image. If I choose category slowly, that my  cell use image ok.

My screen first: if I choose category fast

[image]

second: if I choose category slowly, in the screen everything is good.

If I don't use background async thread, all ok, but everything starts to slow down

Please, any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a background thread and the main thread in a sequential manner while by definition they are parallel and don't wait for one another. Therefore in :

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
     let locImage = Helpers.videoSnapshot(filePathLocal: childPostsItem.media)
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.myImage.image = nil
         self.myImage.image = locImage
     }
}
```

The two threads are completely asynchronous. You can't expect the background thread to be finished before the main thread starts.

There are ways to communicate thread events with *signals* and *semaphores* but in your case I think using asynchronous functions with **completion handlers** would be way more appropriate.

Check out how it works : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531255/5922920

Comment: it didn't help for me.